# BIM model upload to Autodesk Forge and integration with IoT

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am want to develop a forge solution integrating IoT data. I am following this documentation (https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/introduction/overview/)
and have succesfuly loaded a Navisworks model to Forge. The rooms are loaded there as well.
My main problem is that I cannot see any sensors at the viewer. For start, I want to connect my sensors with a CSV option like it is explained here.
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/advanced_topics/csv_adapter/
.
I have uncommented the part at eng file as suggested in the instructions.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0sCG.png)
What are the next steps for seeing the sensors at the viewer?
Probably need to change the files named devices.json, device-models.json ??

Answer (score 0):

sorry for our late response.  This is not a desktop application. It does not make sense with the file path like c:.... you need to use relative path where the json file is stored on the server side of the application. e.g.  In the sample application of Data Visualization, the demo json is stored at
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app/tree/main/server/gateways/synthetic-data

So, to use the data, the environment will be like:

```
ADAPTER_TYPE=csv
CSV_MODEL_JSON=server/gateways/synthetic-data/device-models.json
CSV_DEVICE_JSON=server/gateways/synthetic-data/devices.json
CSV_FOLDER=server/gateways/csv
CSV_DATA_START=2011-02-01T08:00:00.000Z
CSV_DATA_END=2011-02-03T06:13:14.484Z
CSV_DELIMITER=","
CSV_LINE_BREAK="\n"
CSV_TIMESTAMP_COLUMN="time"
CSV_FILE_EXTENSION=".csv"
```

I suggested you download the sample application and run it firstly, which may help you to troubleshoot.